# how to add arbitrary information in manifest from maven assembly plugin

Tags: maven-2, assemblies, manifest, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

i use the assembly plugin to create a uber jar from several maven artifacts.

Now I like to add some company specific entries into the Manifest of the created assembly jar.

But how ?

the `archive` element doesnt allow arbitrary elements (or is there a way to add `foobar: tutu` inside the `archive` tag ?)

also in addition with `maven-jar-plugin` it does not work as this only affects the default artifact of the project and not the assembled.

Any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 22):

argh... after posting it i found it out myself...

```
<archive>
    <manifestEntries>
        <foobar>bla</foobar>
    </manifestEntries>
</archive>
```

works :)