# buildnumber-maven-plugin and maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin, build-numbers, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I've set up the **buildnumber-maven-plugin** to pull the version number from SVN and stash it away in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF inside the jar. That works ok.

But when I try to use it together with the **maven-assembly-plugin** to pack all the other libs together It doesn't seem to work, the version number stuff is not included in the manifest in the ...-jar-with-dependencies.jar.

Has anybody managed to get them to work together?

Alternatively: Is there a (reasonable simple) way to output the ${buildNumber} into a text file (.properties, perhaps) using Maven? An Ant task in Maven could do it I guess but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argh... after posting I found THIS: [how to add arbitrary information in manifest from maven assembly plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864841/how-to-add-arbitrary-information-in-manifest-from-maven-assembly-plugin) and smacked my head.

OK, so My maven-assembly-plugin bit in the pom now looks like this

```
<build> ... <plugins> ...
    <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>...</mainClass>          
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: And I did NOT post a question and an answer to it on purpose. The "Related" column gave me the answer after posting the question...